# Returning 500(Internal server error ) when placing order in magento2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I am a newbie in magento2 and getting a problem when the user placing the order It is returning me 500(Internal server error) I am using one step checkout extension of the mega plaza I am unable to understand what's wrong in my code. Also when I checked error in chrome network console error is in the checkout-information file.

You can check and place an order by [this](https://magento2.petpanic.gr/) Url. Please help me to resolve this error thanks in advanced.

This is the error I am getting

> jquery.js:10254 POST
>
> > https://magento2.petpanic.gr/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/checkout-information
> >     500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Go to your app/bootstrap.php file and uncomment line `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` it will display you error details. Then you can add those details in your question to have more details to debug.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya already uncomment

Comment: Have you tried to purchase a product from the link I shared @magefms

Comment: yeah and it is an error with observer in Temand Shipping

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Temando\Shipping\Model\Checkout\Address::setServiceSelection() must be of the type array, null given`

Comment: check `SaveCheckoutFieldsObserver` from your custom module

Comment: What I have to do with this file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93224/discussion-between-magefms-and-shweta-mudgil).

Answer (score 1):

The error was from Temando Shipping **`SaveCheckoutFieldsObserver.`**
You can try fixing this by overriding **`Temando's SaveCheckoutFieldsObserver`**

In your **`di.xml`** file, add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Temando\Shipping\Observer\SaveCheckoutFieldsObserver" type="Vendor\Module\Observer\Temando\SaveCheckoutFieldsObserver" />
</config>
```

Then create **`observer`** file at:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Temando/SaveCheckoutFieldObserver

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Temando;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Temando\Shipping\Api\Data\Checkout\AddressInterface;
use Temando\Shipping\Api\Data\Checkout\AddressInterfaceFactory;
use Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Repository\AddressRepositoryInterface;

 /**
 * Save checkout fields with quote shipping address.
 *
 */
class SaveCheckoutFieldsObserver extends \Temando\Shipping\Observer\SaveCheckoutFieldsObserver 
{
    /**
     * @var AddressRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $addressRepository;
    /**
     * @var AddressInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $addressFactory;
    /**
     * SaveCheckoutFieldsObserver constructor.
     * @param AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param AddressInterfaceFactory $addressFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressFactory
    ) {
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
    }
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface|\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $quoteAddress */
        $quoteAddress = $observer->getData('quote_address');
        if ($quoteAddress->getAddressType() !== \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::ADDRESS_TYPE_SHIPPING) {
            return;
        }
        if (!$quoteAddress->getExtensionAttributes()) {
            return;
        }
        // persist checkout fields
        try {
            $checkoutAddress = $this->addressRepository->getByQuoteAddressId($quoteAddress->getId());
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $checkoutAddress = $this->addressFactory->create(['data' => [
                AddressInterface::SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ID => $quoteAddress->getId(),
            ]]);
        }
        $extensionAttributes = $quoteAddress->getExtensionAttributes();
        if(!is_array($extensionAttributes)){
            $checkoutAddress->setServiceSelection(array());
        }else{
            $checkoutAddress->setServiceSelection($extensionAttributes->getCheckoutFields());
        }

        $this->addressRepository->save($checkoutAddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: let me try and back to you